# How to update all varchar, nvarchar or char field of a SQL Server database and set empty string in the place of NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database there are a lot of `NULL` values. Now I need to replace all the `NULL` values and set them to empty strings instead, because my existing software has problems with `NULL`  values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurraaaaaaaaa I found the answer......

```
declare @query varchar(MAX)
SET @query='';
select @query=@query+' UPDATE '+table_name+' SET '+column_name+' = isnull('+column_name+','''');'
from (
    SELECT table_name=sysobjects.name,
             column_name=syscolumns.name
        FROM sysobjects 
        JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
        JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
       WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U' and (systypes.name='nvarchar' or systypes.name='varchar' or systypes.name='char')
) as a

exec (@query)
```

Comment: You should **stop using** the `sysobjects` catalog view (SQL Server 2005 or newer) - use the more targetted `sys.tables`, `sys.columns` and `sys.types` instead

Comment: @Parado: I doubt his requirement was as much a "single query" as it was "only have to press F5 once".

Comment: yap. 
actually I don't want to type all my table and column names to update. I needed some solution which can automatically update all NULL fields.
And I found the Solution with the help of @parado. 
He give me the hints to write loop for solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this update:

```
update Table1
set column1 = ' '
where column1 is null
```

Comment: but I have 82 tables and a lot of columns.
If I have to write queries like that then I am in a big trouble.

Is there any way, using which I can update all NULL values using a single query?

Comment: One simple query? No, You have to use loop, take every table with every column, prepare update string as above and run it using `exec` command.